# mysql join tables with many-many connection

Tags: mysql

Мне нужно выбрать все shifts_schedule, из обычными join не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста как нужно правильно делать данную выборку

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(
    shifts_schedule.shifts_schedule_id
  ) 
FROM 
  `shifts_schedule` 
  left JOIN users ON shifts_schedule.agent_id = users.user_id 
  left JOIN user_roles ON users.user_id = user_roles.user_id 
  left JOIN roles ON user_roles.user_id = roles.role_id 
WHERE 
  roles.role_id = '57' 
LIMIT 
  1
```

ps: shift_schedule нужно выбрать по roles.role_id = '(some number)'[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что значит "обычными join не получается" ? Они дают какой то побочный эффект ? Вы бы привели запрос который у вас получился и написали что он не так сделал.

Comment: пример добавил, результат пустой

Comment: Ну а COUNT вы зачем используете?

Comment: И если ваш count дает 0 - то руками пройдитесь по таблицам по заданному условию и убедитесь что все данные там присутствуют.

Comment: count - можно поменять на  * - и ничего не поменятеся - ответ пуст.

Comment: да действительно можно из етой цепочки выкинуть users - но проблема из выборкой все таже остается

Comment: данные ручками вписывал специально для теста - данная выборка неработает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе достаточно такого запроса:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM shifts_schedule
  JOIN user_roles ON shifts_schedule.agent_id = user_roles.user_id 
 WHERE user_roles.role_id = 57
```

- Таблицы users и roles в запросе не нужны, так как необходимые данные и так уже присутствуют в оставшихся двух таблицах.
- left join не нужен, так как он используется *только* в случаях когда мы хотим получить из одной таблицы данные вне зависимости от наличия их в другой

[Запрос на sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63431e/3/0)